# bootstrapping capacitor

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, cmos, vlsi

Please read the text first in image 2. My question is based on that.

Can somebody explain me how there is a small bump in "b" in the graph figure shown. I dont get it why the bump occurs. Initially b is at 5 V and a at 0 V. If a starts increasing why does b also starts increasing? Is there some intuitive capacitative coupling going on here? how do you explain that phenomenon?

[image: graph]

[image: text]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capacitive coupling is shown in the picture. There is a blue 3fF capacitor that couples the input of the inverter to its output.

When node a is at 0V and node b at 5V the capacitor is charged to 5V. As soon as node a rises to 5V, it pushes the a-side of the capacitor to higher voltages, while at the first moment the voltage across the capacitor stays constant, the result is that the voltage at node b rises as well. Then the capacitor starts to discharge across the parasitic diode of the PMOS and the voltage at node b also starts to decrease because the NMOS turns on.

Below a screenshot of a simulation of a simple inverter with an additonal 3fF capacitor between input and output.

[image]

The red trace is the input, green is the output and the yellow curve is the current through the capacitor. Please note the large current spike of almost 1mA.

Comment: On what basis do you say voltage across the capacitor stays constant? it it like some inertial thing that voltage across capacitor dosnt want to change?

Comment: The capacitor can't discharge instantly because at the b-side of the capacitor the current path is through the PMOS transistor and the NMOS transistor. The resistance is initially low, but increases as the PMOS turns off while the NMOS is not yet on. Any RC combination has a certain delay. And edges are often in the 100ps range, so these delays can be seen.

Comment: @Mario: did you use Cadence tool to simulate the inverter? Also how did you get MOS with zero parasitic capacitance? Thanks.

Comment: I did use Cadence, yes. I've added some capacitance to the already existing parasitics to make the effect more pronounced.